# What is the exact difference between user and eng binaries?

Tags: system

What is the exact difference between user and eng binaries for a phone (mobile device)? These are two of the build variants. I want to know the exact difference between them.

Comment: What is this user and eng binaries you are talking about? Do you have a link to the site where we could download them?

Comment: I would like to know the difference between the two build_flavor's,i.e. eng and user build in android.

Answer (score 4):

"Eng" is short for engineering AKA developer build. Those builds have various logging facilities enabled which you do not see on regular "production" builds. Normally you do not want to flash such builds on to your phone.

Comment: Thanks but want to know the things in detail,what all logging facilities are enabled which you are talking about engineering AKA developer build.Can you please enlighten me.

Comment: the exact configuration of the "eng" build depends on the manufacturer/model. this is just a build used internally by manufacturer while developing a product. it even can change for the same product.

Comment: Eng builds usually contain device manufacturer specific hacks and testing apps. In particular network related items. Often `eng` build allows access to hidden service menus  and parts of the OS that is not otherwise present, including unlocked bootloaders. Again, it all depend on the hardware and manufacturer.

Comment: How could you determine or strongly infer if you have an eng or user build on a particular device? Do developers typically adopt conventions like putting suffixes in the OS version in the `About phone` section?